# Adding anchor to AngularJS State

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, anchor, anchor-scroll

I have a state named state.home() that is used to redirect a user to the home pageand this is my state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('state.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: modulePath + '/views/home/home.html',
        controller: 'state:HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeCtr'
    })
```

In another page after doing some work , in my controller i need to redirect the user to a specific Div in the home page, so in my controller i added this line for the redirection but it doesn't seem to be the right way:

```
$state.go('state.home',{'#': 'anchor'});
```

I want to know if it could work with the same state or I have to make a new state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div an id, e.g `<div id="anchor"></div>`

in the controller, navigate to the intended state and use anchor scroll to go to the div. Dont forget to inject `$anchorScroll`

`$state.go('state.home').then(function() {$anchorScroll('anchor');})`

Comment: Hello , thank you for your help , But it dosen't work fine for me.Finally i found a solution for the problem :
 $state.go('state.home')
                                .then(function()
                                {
                                    $location.hash('anchor');
                                    $anchorScroll();
                                });

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `$location.hash(hash)`. `$anchorScroll(hash)` should do it